Number of distinct decompositions of $Z/(p) \oplus Z/(p)$ in a direct sum of two proper subgroups
I have read some similar questions and answers but it was not easy for me to understand them. So I ask you to check my solution. 
The question is to find the number of distinct decompositions of $Z/(p)\oplus Z/(p)$ in a direct sum of two proper subgroups. 
There are $p^2 - 1$ non-zero elements in $Z/(p)\oplus Z/(p)$, each of them generates a proper subgroup of $p$ elements. $p-1$ elements of this subgroup also generate the same group, so the number of proper subgroups is $\frac{p^2-1}{p-1} = p+1$. 
For each proper subgroup $A$ there exists only one subgroup $B$ such that $Z/(p)\oplus Z/(p) = A \oplus B.$ So there are $\frac{p+1}{2}$ distinct decompositions of $Z/(p)\oplus Z/(p)$ in a direct sum of two proper subgroups.

From the solution-verification tag description: ""Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so."

What makes you think each subgroup has one and only one complement?

The claim that:

For each proper subgroup $A$ there exists only one subgroup $B$ such that $Z/(p)\oplus Z/(p) = A\oplus B$.

is false.
For example, if $A=\{(x,0)\mid x\in Z/(p)\}$, then both
$$\begin{align*}
B_1 &= \{(0,y)\mid y\in Z/(p)\},\\
\text{and }B_2 &= \{(y,y)\mid y\in Z/(p)\}
\end{align*}$$
satisfy that $Z/(p)\oplus Z/(p) = A\oplus B$.
In fact, suppose you have two distinct proper nontrivial subgroups $A$ and $B$ of $Z/(p)\oplus Z/(p)$. Then $|A|=|B|=p$, and $|A\cap B| = 1$ (since they are distinct and the intersection must be a subgroup). Therefore,
$$|A+B| = \frac{|A||B|}{|A\cap B|} = \frac{p^2}{1} = p^2,$$
so $A+B=Z/(p)\oplus Z/(p)$. Together with the observation about the intersection, you have that $Z/(p)\oplus Z/(p) = A\oplus B$. Thus, for a fixed $A$, you have $p$ possible choices for $B$ (any other proper nontrivial subgroup).
